# Mocking the initialize method on a ruby class?

Tags: ruby, mocking

How can I mock the initialize method on a ruby class?

I'm doing some testing and want to mock out the object that is created from a new call.

I tried to write a few things and none of them seemed to get the mock class to return from the new call.  It just keeps returning the normal, expected object.

EDIT:

one attempt -

```
class MockReminderTimingInfoParser < ReminderTimingInfoParser
  def new(blank)
    ReminderTimingInfoParserForTest.new
  end
end

describe ReminderParser do
  parser = ReminderParser.new(MockReminderTimingInfoParser)

  it "should parse line into a Reminder" do
    parser.parse(" doesnt matter  \"message\"").should == Reminder.new('message', ReminderTimingInfo.new([DaysOfWeek.new([:sundays])], [1]))
  end
end

class ReminderTimingInfoParserForTest
  include TimingInfoParser

  def parse_section(section); [DaysOfWeek.new([:sundays]), 1] end

  def reminder_times_converter(times); times end
end
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to mock `initialize` or `new`?

Comment: isnt initialize the method that gives you new?  That's a ruby detail I don't know well.

Comment: What do you mean by "that gives you `new`"? The method that gives you `new` is `new`, just like the method that gives you `foobar` is `foobar`.

Comment: when I created a class I don't def new; end, I def initialize; end.  I thought it was some kind of special case in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MockReminderTimingInfoParser < ReminderTimingInfoParser
  def new(blank)
    ReminderTimingInfoParserForTest.new
  end
end
```

Here, you are defining a method called `new` for all instances of the class `MockReminderTimingInfoParser`. In your question, you mention that you want to hook into instance creation. However, in Ruby, instance creation is not done by instance methods. Obviously, this cannot work, since in order to call an instance method, you'd need to have an instance first!

Instead, instances are created by calling a factory method (commonly called `new`) on the class.

In other words, in order to create an instance of `MockReminderTimingInfoParser`, you would call `MockReminderTimingInfoParser.new`, but you have defined a method `MockReminderTimingInfoParser#new`. In order to call the method you have defined, you would have to call `MockReminderTimingInfoParser.new.new`.

You need to define a method on `MockReminderTimingInfoParser`'s singleton class. There's several ways to do that. One way would be just mimicking the way you would *call* the method:

```
def MockReminderTimingInfoParser.new(blank)
  ReminderTimingInfoParserForTest.new
end
```

Another would be opening up `MockReminderTimingInfoParser`'s singleton class:

```
class << MockReminderTimingInfoParser
  def new(blank)
    ReminderTimingInfoParserForTest.new
  end
end
```

However, in both of these cases, `MockReminderTimingInfoParser` obviously has to exist first. Given that you need to define the class anyway, here's the most idiomatic way of defining methods on a class's (or module's) singleton class:

```
class MockReminderTimingInfoParser < ReminderTimingInfoParser
  def self.new(blank)
    ReminderTimingInfoParserForTest.new
  end
end
```

Comment: either way neither seems to be working.  IF you have an example snippet of code that works, I'd love to see it.

Comment: thanks!  I just figured this out via some blog posts, but your answer is excellent, thanks again.  Some of your code gives me cleaner ways to do what I got working.

Comment: I especially liek this syntax:

Comment: def ReminderTimingInfoParser.new(*args)
  ReminderTimingInfoParserForTest.new
end

Answer (score 0):

Could you inherit the class and then supply your own initialize?

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't seem to work.  I'll post my code in an edit to the question.